# Animation using Animated.View not working on iOS after upgrading react-native to 59.0

Tags: react-native

We have a custom loader that works great on Android but after upgrading, the loader just stays on the initial animation. We are using the `Animated` import to create a series of `Animated.View` that scale up and down to create our loader. Has anyone experienced this issue when upgrading React-Native?

Comment: Some code would be really appreciated to understand your problem mate. Your question is too abstract to come to a conclusion. RN is not that predictable in itself so cannot say if the upgrade would be a reason.

Comment: @SurajMalviya the animation seems to work fine in release mode but not in debug